# Не получается присвоить значение элементу массива

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

не могу разобраться, почему возникает ошибка при второй итерации for. Cуть функции: Считывает данные из файла. Первая строка - количество элементов, а начиная со второй координаты.Возможно я неправильно выделяю память? Или проблема с указателями ?

```
//Текстовый файл:

  /*12
    23 21
    32 43*/



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read_point(double **mas_point) {
    int points_count = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen("read_file/biz_points.txt", "r");

    /*Выделение памяти по массив*/
    if (fscanf(file, "%d", &points_count) != 0) {
        printf("points count - %d\n", points_count);
        *mas_point = (double*)(double**)malloc(2 * points_count * sizeof(double));

    }

    /*Считывание икса и игрика*/
    double x = 0, y = 0;
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < points_count; i++) {
        fscanf(file, "%lf %lf", &x, &y);
        *(*(mas_point + i) + j) = x; //при i = 1 тут возникает ошибка
        *(*(mas_point + i) + j + 1) = y;
        printf("point - %.2lf %.2lf\n",mas_point[i][j] , mas_point[i][j + 1]);
    }


    fclose(file);
    return points_count;
}

int main() {
    double *point;
    int a = read_point(&point);

    printf("%f", *(point));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка то?

Comment: Ошибка сегментирования. Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с неверного выделения памяти. Ну, как неверного? Если выделяете так, то обращаться нужно не как к `mas_point[i][j]`. Я бы для простоты на вашем месте делал так:

```
int read_point(double ***points)
{
    // ...
    double ** pts = malloc(2*sizeof(double*));    // (double**)malloc, если C++
    pts[0] = malloc(points_count*sizeof(double)); // (double*)malloc, если C++
    pts[1] = malloc(points_count*sizeof(double)); // (double*)malloc, если C++

    *points = pts;  // Для возврата

    //...
    pts[0][i] = x;
    pts[1][i] = y;

    //...
}
```

Так проще, можно обращаться через индексы, не надо кучи звездочек. Только не забудьте потом освободить память...